# Timestamp to ISO 8601 in Lua

Tags: nginx, lua, timestamp, iso8601, date-conversion

How would you convert a timestamp to an ISO 8601 format (such as `2009-01-28T21:49:59.000Z`) in Lua?

I'm specifically trying to do it by using the [HttpLuaModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule) in Nginx.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try `os.date("!%Y-%m-%dT%TZ")` or `os.date("!%Y-%m-%dT%TZ",t)` if `t` has the date in seconds since the epoch.

Comment: This works except that `%M` should be lowercase: `%m`. Answer updated.

Comment: FWIW, this does not work on Windows on Lua 5.3.4, producing: `bad argument #1 to 'date' (invalid conversion specifier '%TZ')`. Fixed version: `os.date("!%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")`

Answer (score 1):

You asked to include milliseconds, so there is a little gymnastics involved because the os.date format doesn't permit milliseconds.
This works when running in Nginx (which was the context of your question)

```
-- Return a ISO 8061 formatted timestamp in UTC (Z)
-- @return e.g. 2021-09-21T15:20:44.323Z
local function iso_8061_timestamp()
    local now = ngx.now()                               -- 1632237644.324
    local ms = math.floor((now % 1) * 1000)             -- 323 or 324 (rounding)
    local epochSeconds = math.floor(now)
    return os.date("!%Y-%m-%dT%T", epochSeconds) .. "." .. ms .. "Z"  -- 2021-09-21T15:20:44.323Z
end
```

Note the useful date format reference here: https://developpaper.com/lua-os-date-notes/

Answer (score -1):

Or you can use:

```
local now_date_time = os.date("!%Y%m%dT%H%M%S") --> For date_time: 20191015T042028Z

local now_date = os.date("!%Y%m%d") --> For only date: 20191015
```