# how to convert seconds to iso 8601 format in Lua?

Tags: time, lua, intervals, iso8601

i want to convert seconds to iso 8601 format in Lua, But i'm not able to find it, can anyone help?
ex: 60.001 secs --> PT1M0.001S

Comment: Have you tried writing code to do it?  I don't think the built-ins are going to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Start with

```
t = os.date("*t",os.time({day=1, month=1, year=2000, hour=0, min=0, sec=60.001}))
```

Then build the string from the fields in `t`, subtracting 1 from `t.day` and `t.month` and 2000 from `t.year`. The call to `os.time` takes care of the arithmetic, which is the boring part, but unfortunately does not support fractions of seconds.

The code above worked before Lua 5.3 but it now raises an error when `sec` does not contain an integer.
A better solution is

```
sec = 60.001
fsec = sec%1
sec = math.floor(sec)
t = os.date("*t",os.time({day=1, month=1, year=2000, hour=0, min=0, sec=sec}))
t.sec = t.sec + fsec
```

Comment: i'm getting error as "field 'sec' is not an integer" for above solution.

Answer (score -1):

You want use only such time periods as 60s / 180 s.

If you will use timestamps, maybe that solution can help?

[Timestamp to ISO 8601 in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131891/timestamp-to-iso-8601-in-lua?rq=1)